# Upgrading from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, migration, upgrade, drupal-7

I'm trying to find a way to migrate my Drupal 6 website to Drupal 7. I want to migrate all my content types.

How do I do that?

Comment: Read [Upgrading from Drupal 6 to 7](http://drupal.org/documentation/upgrade/6/7). If you have written your own modules, read [Converting 6.x modules to 7.x](http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7). If you have written your own theme, read [Converting 6.x themes to 7.x](http://drupal.org/node/254940).

Answer (score 4):

Have you read through the Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 upgrade guide? http://drupal.org/documentation/upgrade/6/7

Try reading through that, try upgrading on your local computer or a development machine (make sure you keep a backup of your database and codebase), and come back and ask more specific questions...

If you have a relatively simple Drupal site, things should go fairly well. If you have a very complex site, you might need to consider migrating your site instead of simply upgrading (meaning: export your content, rebuild the site in Drupal 7, and reimport it into the Drupal 7 site).

For many people, at this point, it's a good idea to stick with Drupal 6 for a few more months if you don't need any features in Drupal 7. I've upgraded a few of my sites, but I can say with confidence that a couple Drupal 6 sites I run will have to wait at least 6 months before Drupal 7 and the important modules I use are stable enough for a seamless upgrade.

Comment: m gtin stuck with an error saying blocked_ips table not found..

Comment: @PiyueshKumar: Which of the [Solutions on drupal.org](http://drupal.org/search/apachesolr_multisitesearch/table%20blocked_ips%20not%20found) have you tried already?

Comment: Yeah - there are probably a few little gotchas you'll run into. Try searching google for `site:drupal.org error_reported here` for each problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've listed the steps I took here (http://www.siteconsortium.com/h/D0000Q.php) to do full upgrade. It worked pretty well.

Start out by upgrading the entire database from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7. This will migrate your content types and preserve all the content.

I backed up the Drupal 6 database, and also backed up the working Drupal 6 webroot directory.

mysqldump -uuser -ppass drupalDB > drupalDB_6.sql
cp -r public_html public_html.back
Go to drupal7/admin/modules and take inventory of all your modules. Non-core modules will not upgrade. And you may have to manually re-add the modules and reconfigure them following the upgrade.

I brought the database from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 by downloading a recent copy of Drupal 7 source and copying its contents into Drupal 6.

cp -r drupal-7.26/* public_html/.
To finis the database upgrade you simply open your website and drupal/ and follow the steps to upgrade the site.

After you run the upgrade save the database if you like and use it with Drupal 7.

Here are the full steps I took.

http://www.siteconsortium.com/h/D0000Q.php

Answer (score 0):

steps:

1. backup your site
2. upgrade drupal core
3. run update.php
4. then put back all non core  modules and themes for new version
5. run update.php again

follow upgrade.txt in root directory; it elaborates on all processes nicely